# How to receive RTSP stream with Xuggler with additional ffmpeg commandline options?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, xuggler

I'm able to get RTSP stream with Xuggler from IP camera with default UDP transport, but it generates errors like [Thread-6] ERROR org.ffmpeg - [h264 @ 00000000489652B0] corrupted macroblock
I googled that ffmpeg internal UDP parser causing that, although with fresh downloaded ffmpeg binaries (ffmpeg.exe, ffplay.exe), opening same stream from IP camera works just fine.

So I tried to get RTP TCP stream with ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp option. But adding that option in Java code
    `container.setProperty("rtsp_transport", "tcp");`
but nothing happens, stream is still UDP.

How to overcome with RTP UDP streaming problem and how is it possible to switch rtsp stream transport to tcp with Xuggler?

Forward Thanks